Can unused cable clamps be removed from the back of a device/junction box?
Consider a device box like this one, which has 8 knockouts and 4 integrated cabled clamps:

In most installations, only a few of the knockouts are actually used, with some of the cable clamps having no cables to ... clamp. Is it safe and code-compliant to remove the unused one clamp plates and their screws?
I'm asking mostly out of curiosity, but also because removing them would free up some room. E.g. I've seen a few boxes with switches for separate circuits, each with their own neutral. I like to tuck those neutrals out of the way in the back, and it'd be nice to free up the extra room along the back edges of the box for them.

Since I don't know for sure what code would dictate I won't make this an answer, but I can't imagine removing those clamps would be a code violation if they're not being used to clamp any incoming conduit, metal flex, or other cabling.  You're not changing the integrity or protection the metal box would provide.

Running the clamps down does serve to cover the openings in the box. Since NEC requires that unused holes be capped I would expect that removing the clamps and leaving the holes uncovered would be a violation. Note that the clamps are designed with a flange that covers the holes as it is tightened.

@Milwrdfan I had the same gut feeling, but we’ve seen plenty of examples of those being wrong on this site :D

@HABO There would still be the (still intact) knock out panels covering the holes where the cables otherwise go. There would just be one new empty screw hole, but the junction box already has plenty of holes if that size, as you can see in this example picture

Unless you have another immediate use for the clamps or machine screws and want to save a few pennies, removing them sounds like more work than it is worth?

If you really want to remove them, the DO make plugs for the knockouts. https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-Electric-ProConnex-3-4-in-Knockout-Seal-Conduit-Fitting/1100047?store=191&cm_mmc=shp--c--prd--elc--ggl--CRP_SHP_LIA_ELC_Online_E-F--1100047--local--0-_-0&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAl4a6BhBqEiwAqvrquugGesmNsL7lWwPRbf07D-Gr5s0K1LV9NaAYoNsSC0Nd2m84HgpysRoCZnYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

The clamps are an optional feature. If they're unused, they may be removed. That would leave a situation no different than one where clamps aren't provided. That said, the space they occupy when fully tightened is negligible, assuming legal box fill and neat workpersonship.
If the knockout has been removed, the clamp would need to remain in place and secured. The only other reason to leave them in place would be for future usage as a courtesy.
